# Bind / Live Load Event on Dynamic HTML img Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, waitforimages

In this example, I can get the following code to create the dynamic image in `div#add` element when I click the button, but the load event for the `img` does not work.

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>None!</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts\jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
 </head>                                                                 
 <body>
    <button id="click">Click</button>
 <div id="add"></div>

 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#click').click(function() {
            $('div#add').append('<img src="./images/imagename.jpg" />');
        });

        $('img').bind('load',function(){
            alert('test');
        });
    });
 </script>

 </body>                                                                 
 </html>
```

I have also tried setting the `onload` event on the dynamic `img` but I did not get the event to fire. Any help is much appreciated.

---

**Update (2011-10-24 18:55 EST)**: It appears that JQuery documentation for [Load-Event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) states the following.

> Caveats of the load event when used with images
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load()
>   shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of
>   images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with
>   this that should be noted. These are:
>
> -It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
>   -It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
>   -It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
>   -Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

### I guess using the load event is not a fail safe, cross-browser solution.

**Update (2011-10-28 15:05 EST)**: Thanks to @Alex, I was able to use his [waitForImages](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) plugin and make a listener (I'm not sure if that is the right term) to determine when an image has been loaded.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>None!</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts\jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts\jquery.waitforimages.js"></script>
</head>                                                          
<body>

<button id="click">Click</button>
<div id="add"></div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $('div#add img.art').waitForImages(function() {
            $('div#add img.load').hide();
            $(this).show();
        });
    }, 500);

    $('#click').click(function() {
        $('div#add').append('<img class="load" src="./images/loading.gif" /><img style="display:none;" width="199" class="art" src="./images/imagename.jpg" /><br />');
    });
});
</script>

</body>                                                                 
</html>
```

So right now there is a maximum of 500 ms lag in determining if an image has been loaded. Does this seem reasonable? Is this the best way to see if a dynamically created img tag has been loaded?

**Outstanding: I have to stop the `setInterval` function from triggering after all of the images have been loaded. I still have to work out the details on that.**

Comment: You need to use jQuery's [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event handler

Comment: I have tried '.live()' and it does not work with images.

Answer (score 3):

Change `bind()` to [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and rejig the arguments accordingly.

When you simply `bind()`, it binds to all elements in the DOM. When you use `on()`, it looks for events bubbling to your common ancestor and then checks their origin and fires any attached events.

This means it will handle all future `img` elements.

Comment: I tried both `bind` and `live` and neither trigger the alert.

Comment: @JoeFletch: That probably has to do with `live()` not working with `load` event.

Comment: See my edit, JQuery documentation says that the `load-event` is not consistent with img tags. Thoughts?

Comment: @JoeFletch: Yeah, it can be a bit funky. I wrote a [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) to deal with loading of images, it may be appropriate here.

Comment: Take a look at my most recent edit. Does this appear to be a good method of detecting if a dynamic `img` has been loaded?